# Declare 2D Dynamic Array and Populate from Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

I'm relatively new to C++ and using OpenCV to create and train an SVM. However I am getting a bad access error for memory location 0x0 when using the trainAuto() method. Presumably the fact this is OpenCV doesn't really matter as it's an issue with the pointer manipulation. My current code is below. It should make a 2D array of size NUMIMGS*NUMVECTORS. Please let me know if you spot any reason why I might be going out of memory or not allocating properly... FYI NUMIMGS and NUMVECTORS are 20 and 15000 respectively, so this is a very large array of floats.

So now I am getting EXC_ARITHMETIC code=EXC_I386_DIV subcode=0x0, presumably it is trying to operate on the dataset but is rejecting 0 value entries?

Comment: what is `thisSVM` and where is it getting initialized?

Comment: Hi Stephan, thisSVM is declared globally as `Ptr<ml::SVM> thisSVM;` and then in the method that calls the code above it is initialised as  `thisSVM = ml::SVM::create();` (If you are wondering it is definitely called before this code is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part looks suspicious:

```
trainDataFloats[i] = thisHog;
```

1. You have already assigned a value to `trainDataFloats[x]` so you are leaking memory and probably setting `trainDataFloats[i]` to point to something it shouldn't.
2. `i` here is looping up to `NUMIMGS`, but `trainDataFloats` was allocated with `NUMVECTORS` elements, if `NUMIMGS` is greater than `NUMVECTORS` you will have a buffer overrun. It isn't in this particular case, but it does indicate something is going wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help. I have taken this into account and redesigned the function. I also removed the unnecessary float array in the loop, however amazingly it still comes out with bad access. I don't suppose there is anything I have forgotten to consider you can see? I've modified my question with the updated code